# Why white spaces are not considered as white spaces when we declare header file in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

When we declare header file in c++. It is not recommended to insert white spaces between angular braces '<' '>'  and header file name.  If we insert it comes out with an error.
I have tried in Xcode and various other IDE's

```
// It is perfectly valid ( in c++ )
#include <iostream> 

but 

// It is invalid
#include < iostream >
```

Comment: You can have whitespace in filenames (in some OSs at least). Maybe it would be clearer if you think about the case where you use quotes: `#include " myfile.h "`. Using `<>` instead of quotes just tells the compiler to check a different location for the file first.

Comment: Having white spaces is just purely bad practice and invitation to all kinds of problems. I don't think any professional dev cares. We're programmed to eliminate spaces in file names, either with camel case or snake case.

Comment: You can use white spaces. It just includes files. "file.h", " file.h", "file 1.h", file.h " are all different files. As a good practice, avoid white spaces. Its better to replace it with underscore.

Comment: @HelloWorld thank you for helping me sir but if I'm including white spaces in file name. My code doesn't compile

Comment: @PraveenKumar as I/we said " iostream" and "iostream" are different files. You must create " iostream" header in order to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no header file named iostream that begins and ends with a space character, so that's why you get an error.

The name, all of the characters, inside the `<>` or "" when you use #include designates a header name (with most implementations it refers to a physical file name)

If you include one of your own header files with e.g.

```
#include " file.h "
```

it will look for a file with the name file.h (that begins and ends with a space).

That's a different filename than any of these two:

```
#include "file.h "
#include "file.h"
```